# Using a loop to build a list

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I'm trying to take a list and then plot it with complex variables.

However, when I'm making my list I keep getting

> Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {test, nu}

and my list is not getting written to. It's probably a simple to fix, but

Here is what I have:

```
sig= -15
While[sig <12, tau = Sqrt[sig + 4];
nu = Tan[sig - (1/sig)*E^(sig)];
Print[sig, nu];
sig = sig + 1.00];
For[sig, test= {test, nu}];
ListPlot[test, sig]
```

This is probably just poorly written code, but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Before you get to the plot part, you need to fix your While loop. What happenes when `sig=0` and you have `1/sig` in there?  Did you not hear a beep when you run the `While` loop?  may be the sound was off on your computer, but my PC beeped loud and then noticed you are dividing by zero. You are starting from `-15` and end at `12` so it will pass through `0`

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. If I try to fix that, then it says that there are too many arguments in the loop.  I could just replace the value of `sig` to -15.01.

Comment: Is this what you really want: `Plot[Tan[sig - (1/sig)*E^(sig)], {sig, -15, 12}]`

Comment: I don't really want to use `Plot` because I'm just searching for test points to use and then to use `ListPlot` in order to show each individual thing, not its own connection.

Comment: Your `For` is of incorrect syntax.  It needs at least 3 parameters; ideally 4. You only have 2 parameters. Your `ListPlot` is also of incorrect syntax. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be made to work by modifying like so.

```
data =
 Module[{sig = -15., tau, nu, pts = {}},
   While[sig < 12.,
     tau = Sqrt[sig + 4];
     nu = Quiet @ Check[Tan[sig - (1/sig)*E^(sig)], Null];
     pts = Join[pts, {{sig, tau, nu}}];
     sig++];
   pts]
```

> ```
> {{-15., 0. + 3.31662 I, 0.855993}, {-14., 0. + 3.16228 I, -7.2446}, 
>  {-13., 0. + 3. I, -0.463021}, {-12., 0. + 2.82843 I, 0.635861}, 
>  {-11., 0. + 2.64575 I, 226.028}, {-10., 0. + 2.44949 I, -0.648354}, 
>  {-9., 0. + 2.23607 I, 0.452332}, {-8., 0. + 2. I, 6.80169}, 
>  {-7., 0. + 1.73205 I, -0.871219}, {-6., 0. + 1.41421 I, 0.291454}, 
>  {-5., 0. + 1. I, 3.39734}, {-4., 0., -1.14716}, 
>  {-3., 1., 0.159521}, {-2., 1.41421, 2.6444}, 
>  {-1., 1.73205, -0.732368}, {0., 2., Null}, 
>  {1., 2.23607, 6.73109}, {2., 2.44949, 8.04072}, 
>  {3., 2.64575, -0.618051}, {4., 2.82843, -0.228622}, 
>  {5., 3., 0.48319}, {6., 3.16228, -43.6138}, 
>  {7., 3.31662, 2.14509}, {8., 3.4641, -0.19751}, 
>  {9., 3.60555, 1.1845}, {10., 3.74166, 0.187236}, 
>  {11., 3.87298, -0.298515}}
> ```

Since the `sig` values are in column 1 of `data` and the `nu` values are in column 3, `nu` can be plotted against `sig` with

```
ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 3}]]]
```

[image: plot]

However, I would point out that you can build `data` much more easily with `Table`, Mathematica's basic tool for making lists.

```
data = 
  Table[
    {sig, Sqrt[sig + 4], Quiet @ Check[Tan[sig - (1/sig)*E^(sig)], Null]}, 
    {sig, -15., 11., 1.}]
```